# Load a function in a cshtml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, partial-views

I'm working on a Web Application that has 4 nav-tabs.

The main cshtml file called index.cshtml contains the 4 nav-tabs as partial views:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="mainTab" >
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="@ViewData["Stamp"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stempel-tab">
          @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
          @{Html.RenderAction("_Stempel", "Home");}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@ViewData["BackDated"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="backdated-tab">
          @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
           @{Html.RenderAction("_BackDated", "Home");}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@ViewData["History"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="historie-tab">
           @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
           @{Html.RenderAction("_Historie", "Home");}
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@ViewData["ChangePin"]" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="changepin-tab">
           @{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
           @{Html.RenderAction("_Pinaendern", "Home");}          
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Historie.cshtml file has 2 functions:

```
ShowBookings();
CleanNoHistoryMessage();
```

if I place the functions inside document.ready I need to update every time the WebApp to execute the functions.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        ShowBookings();
        CleanNoHistoryMessage();

    });
```

**Historie.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            ShowBookings();
            CleanNoHistoryMessage();

        });


        function ShowBookings() {

             // Some Code
            }

        function CleanNoHistoryMessage() {

            // Some Code
            }


    </script>

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <h3>@ViewData["TextLabel_BookingHistoryHeadline"]</h3>

    <ul data-role="listview">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">

            <ul id="Liste">
                <li>@ViewData["TextLabel_BookingHistoryNoBookings"]</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

     </ul>
```

I want to execute these functions every time I click on the tab. How can I do that?

Comment: Do little research before posting questions like these

Comment: I'm not an expert like you Stupid Kid

Comment: I am not an expert neither, I just learned how to use google search before programming :D

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery [**.on()**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) Event Handler Attachment :

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

to be spicifique on click, so you code would be like :

```js
$("#mainTab .tab-pane").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).text() + "Is clicked");
  /*    ShowBookings();
        CleanNoHistoryMessage(); */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content" id="mainTab">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stempel-tab">
    tab1
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="backdated-tab">
    tab2
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="historie-tab">
    tab3
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="changepin-tab">
    tab4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The functions are defined in historie.cshtml file. The tabs are defined in index.cshtml. The Event Handler will be placed in index.cshtml. How can I use functions from another cshtml file?

Comment: @JohannaGonzalez , why dont you remove those function to the head or header or footer and call them when  ever you want

Comment: I don't want to call them inside document.ready because historie.cshtml displays some records that change constantly. I want to update these records every time I click on the tab History and not every time I update the whole page. How to call these functions in HIstorie.cshtml or Index.cshtml?